# how to set minimum value in spinbox (fuelux)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

I'm trying to set minimum value in the spinbox component of fuelux.

I execute this code:

```
$('.spinbox').spinbox('min', 1);
```

but Firefox give me this error in (fuelux.min.js):

```
TypeError: g[b] is undefined
..."fu.spinbox",g=new c(this,h)),"string"==typeof b&&(d=g[b].apply(g,e))});return v...
```

Can anyone help me ?

spinbox code: http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#spinbox-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have debug the core plugin and found what is happen:

in the demo page of fuel ux, the guide provide this code:

```
<div class="spinbox" data-initialize="spinbox" id="mySpinbox">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-mini spinbox-input">
      <div class="spinbox-buttons btn-group btn-group-vertical">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default spinbox-up btn-xs">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span><span class="sr-only">Increase</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default spinbox-down btn-xs">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span><span class="sr-only">Decrease</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

but there is a bug in the plugin when `data-initialize="spinbox"` is present.

So use the html code above without `data-initialize="spinbox"` and initialise the componenent with your prefered options like this:

```
$('#mySpinbox').spinbox({
  'value': 1,
  'min' : 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value inside options object at initialization:

```
 $('.spinbox').spinbox({
    value: '1,0px',
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    step: 0.1,
    decimalMark: ',',
    units: ['px']
 });
```

Comment: You gave the answer one day before, the next day he wrote almost the same thing and marked is own answer as valide. feel sorry for you @Ragnar